# React custom Component(DataTable)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, asp.net-core, react-redux

im new to react and im trying to build a custom componenet with parameters.

Im just wonding whats the exact way on doing it.

Here is my current code, how should i pass those `Columns`,`ajax` and `datasource` to the componenet.
Or im i doing it wrong?

```
import * as React from 'react';
interface Column {
    name: string,
    header: string,
    value: Function
}
export default class DataTable extends React.PureComponent<({
    dataSource: any[],
    ajax: string
    columns: Column[]
    onEdit: Function,
    onDelete: Function
})>{

    public state = {
        dataSource: [],
        ajax: undefined,
        columns: [],
        onEdit: undefined,
        onDelete: undefined
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        if (this.state.ajax != undefined) {
            fetch(this.state.ajax)
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => this.setState({ dataSource: data }));
        }
    }

    render() {

        var template = (
            <table className="table">
                <thead className="thead-darked">
                    {
                        this.state.columns.map((x: Column) => {
                            <th scope="col">{x.header}</th>
                        })
                    }
                </thead>

            </table>)
        return template;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You don't need `ajax`, `columns`, `onEdit`, and `onDelete` state. Just use the props.
2. Initialize `this.state.dataSource` with `this.props.dataSource`.

Two changes above will resolve your problem. Additionally,

1. You may want to fetch the data again if `ajax` prop changes. You have to implement `componentDidUpdate` method for the behavior. However, I recommend making a function component and using `useEffect` hook.
2. Your `dataSource` state won't be updated if `dataSource` prop changes. It can lead to a buggy behavior though you can add more code to avoid bugs. If you move the "ajax" part outside of the component and only use `dataSource` prop, the logic will be clearer and less bug-prone.

Below is the updated code.

```js
interface Props {
    dataSource: any[],
    ajax: string,
    columns: Column[],
    onEdit: Function,
    onDelete: Function
}

export default class DataTable extends React.PureComponent<Props>{
  public state = {
    dataSource: this.props.dataSource,
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.ajax != undefined) {
      fetch(this.props.ajax)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => this.setState({ dataSource: data }));
    }
  }

  render() {
    const template = (
      <table className="table">
        <thead className="thead-darked">
          {
            this.props.columns.map((x: Column) => {
              <th scope="col">{x.header}</th>
            })
          }
        </thead>
        {/* render something with this.state.dataSource */} 
      </table>
    );
    return template;
  }
}
```

Comment: I want some parameters to be optional, eg use ajaxUrl or datasource. not both. is that possiable? and also could show me how to create one with ajaxUrl only and another with datasource only. will accept this as an answer then thax

Comment: @Alen.Toma In that case, I suggest not using two different props because you cannot guarantee only one of the two props will be set. How about typing dataSource prop with `any[] | string`? Then you can check the type of dataSource by checking `typeof dataSource === 'string'`. If it's true, it must be a URL for an ajax request and you can do whatever with the URL.

Comment: after some research a could add anuulable property with ? sign eg datasource?: and ajaxUrl?:. but typeof could still work to.

Comment: @Alen.Toma Your solution will work. But as I wrote on the comment above, if you make both props optional you have to handle either when both props are undefined or both props are defined.